# Unable to install "MRP" module in Odoo Community 14

Tags: python, odoo

I'm unable to install [Manufacturing Resource Planning (MRP)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/14.0/addons/mrp) module in Odoo Community 14.

I receive error message below:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 682, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 358, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 346, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 911, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 530, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1363, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1351, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-72>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 73, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 474, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 592, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 455, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 348, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 221, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 733, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 719, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 684, in _tag_root
    etree.tostring(rec, encoding='unicode').rstrip()
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/mrp/data/mrp_data.xml:17, near
<record id="stock.warehouse0" model="stock.warehouse">
     <field name="manufacture_to_resupply" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

Did I forget to configure something (route, ...) specific?

I run Odoo Community 14 containerized, based on official Docker image.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: That mentioned code is 7 years old. Are you sure it's the official docker image and is that a brand new database or a datebase already used before?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I confirm I run official Docker image (Odoo Community Edition version 14.0-20201112) from Docker Hub. I've implemented Odoo a while ago, it's running smooth. Haven't had any issues installing other modules. Code mentioned appears on error screen when I try to install module. I've found a [similar](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/in-odoo-purchase-app-installation-i-got-following-error-157458) issue, however there it seems related to field `buy_to_resupply` instead of `manufacture_to_resupply`. Perhaps it's related to gobal route rules as mentioned in that post?

Comment: My question about "was database already used" was leading to a guess: did you delete something in stock app like warehouses or locations or picking types, before the installation of the mrp app? If yes, try to update module `base` to get those things back.

Comment: Updating `base` module fixed the issue. Thanks a lot! Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept your comment as solution?

Comment: That was only a wild guess and from my point of view not an acceptable answer. It's like with Windows: restart is the most powerful solution on that crappy OS, but i would never accept that as an good answer to mysterious problems :-D